# Running PowerShell script as whole doesn't work but running in batches works

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

Running the following script all together (as a ps1 file) doesn't set the permissions correctly on the private key and gives me this error when I navigate to manage private keys on the certificate.

[image: Error]

However if I run all the commands in the same order, but in small batches, I am able to see the private key permissions and don't see the error as when running all together. Running in large batches (3 separate commands) also doesn't work so don't think its a command line/file thing

What am I doing wrong?

```cs
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Delete current certificates
Remove-Item cert:\LocalMachine\Root\asdfasdfadfasf
Remove-Item cert:\LocalMachine\My\asdfasdfadfasf -DeleteKey

# Add the new certificate to the correct stores
$certBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("cert as base 64")
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certBytes, "password", "MachineKeySet,PersistKeySet")
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My", "LocalMachine")
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
$store2 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("Root", "LocalMachine")
$store2.Open("ReadWrite")
$store2.Add($cert)
$store2.Close()

# Get the certificate added above
$certificate = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" |
               Where thumbprint -eq "asdfasdfadfasf"
if ($certificate -eq $null) {
    $message = "Certificate with thumbprint:asdfasdfadfasf does not exist at Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Red
    exit 1;
} else {
    # Get the private key permissions
    $rsaCert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($certificate)
    $fileName = $rsaCert.key.UniqueName
    $path = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\$fileName"
    $permissions = Get-Acl -Path $path

    #  Get the appPool user
    $site = Get-IISSite -Name 'website'
    $appPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $site.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName
    $appPoolUser = "IIS AppPool\"+$appPool.Name

    # Give read permissions on the private key
    $access_rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($appPoolUser, 'Read', 'None', 'None', 'Allow')
    $permissions.AddAccessRule($access_rule)
    Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $permissions
}
```

Comment: So the issue is with permissions only (`else` part of `if`)? Have you tried to check result of commandlets you're calling there?

Comment: There is no ned to repeat the `$certificate = Get-ChildItem...` in the `else` block. Does `$fileName` (and therefore `$path`) contain only valid characters? Does the $path actually exist?

Comment: I'm confused about the where clause. What is thumbprint? Doesn't it need `$_.` in front or something?

Comment: @PalleDue No (assuming the OP is using a recent enough PowerShell version). PowerShell v3 introduced a simplified syntax for `Where-Object` filters that allows expressing `Where-Object {$_.<property> <op> <value>}` as `Where-Object <property> <op> <value>`.

Comment: @Theo Sorry, left the double get-child in there from testing. I've updated the script. Everything works as expected if I run the commands in small batches in the same order. Eg 1.run the delete certificates first 2. run the add certificates 3. Get the appPool identity 4. Set the permissions on the private key. Doing it this way works but not as a single file.

Comment: @montonero Checking the permissions in powershell window is correct even though the MMC.exe UI doesn't show correctly. That will do for now! Thanks all